# MD5 Verification Error on Flex SDK installation

Tags: apache, actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, air

Somehow, I keep on getting this error

Installer version 3.2.0 (windows)
Using Locale: en_US
Fetched the SDK download mirror URL from the CGI.
SDK version Apache Flex SDK 4.14.1
AIR version 16.0
Flash Player version 16.0
Creating Apache Flex home
Creating temporary directory
Downloading Apache Flex SDK from: http://mirror.rise.ph/apache/flex/4.14.1/binaries/apache-flex-sdk-4.14.1-bin.zip
Verifying Apache Flex SDK MD5 Signature
The Apache Flex SDK MD5 Signature of the downloaded files does not match the reference value. The file is invalid, installation is aborted.
Installation aborted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like an issue with the Apache Flex Installer.  If you post the console log on dev@flex.apache.org, someone should be able to look into it.

Comment: it seems like that network problem occurs in downloading the binaries ... after a while when my network becomes stable.